# Move the camera in the direction its looking

Tags: opengl, camera

I am rotating the camera around itself (when the camera is located at (0,0,0)) using the following:

```
glRotatef(x_camera_angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(y_camera_angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

I wish to move the camera in the direction its looking. For example, I want to move the camera 5 units right and 3 units forward. How can this be done?

I know that there's a lot of information out there, but I have yet to find a satisfying and simple answer.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're imaging a game like an FPS, where only `y_camera_angle` affects the direction of travel, or should the player genuinely move in the direction they're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is probably to translate before the rotate:

```
glTranslatef(5, 0, 3);
glRotatef(x_camera_angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(y_camera_angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```